# Read the list of Ids from nested JSON

Tags: javascript

I need to read the ids from nested loop using Javascript.

Input:

```
let data = [3,[{
"Id": 30,
"Name":"John"
},{
"Id": 33,
"Name":"Jill"
},{
"Id": 34,
"Name":"Jerena"
}]]
```

Output:

```
[30,33,34]
```

I'm stuck with this from sometime. Using maps
`let Ids = [data[0][1]].map(a => a.Id);`

Comment: What are the backslashes for? In JavaScript, that's a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Corrected the code snippet

Comment: `data` is not a string and cannot therefore be JSON, it's a JavaScript Array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
let data = [3,[{
"Id": 30,
"Name":"John"
},{
"Id": 33,
"Name":"Jill"
},{
"Id": 34,
"Name":"Jerena"
}]]

console.log(data[1].map(r => r.Id))
```

Comment: getting this error map' does not exist on type 'number | { Id: number; name: string}[]'.
  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'number'.

Comment: @User45734 Then you input is different from what you posted in the question. This snippet works just fine

Comment: let datat = [3,[{
      "Id": 30,
      "Name":"John"
      },{
      "Id": 33,
      "Name":"Jill"
      },{
      "Id": 34,
      "Name":"Jerena"
      }]]
  let InteriorIds = datat[1].map(r => r.Id); Any issue in my code you see needs a fix?

Comment: @User45734 Works: https://imgur.com/a/GFL41J1

Answer (score 0):

yours example:

`let Ids = [data[0][1]].map(a => a.Id);`

so, you have an array with 2 items

the first element with index = 0 will be number `3`

the second element with index = 1 will be an array.

so:

```
console.log(data[0]) // 3
console.log(data[1]) // [...]
```

or we can use destructuring

```
const [firstNumber, array] = data;
//then
cosnt ids = array.map(i => i.Id)
```

UPDATE:
if you are using `typescript` and getting this error:

`getting this error map' does not exist on type 'number | { Id: number; name: string}[]'. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'number'.`

You need to defined type of variable correcly.

we can use `tuple types`

```
var employee: [number, { Id: number; name: string}[]] = [1, [...]];
```

Comment: Tuples works just fine.